# How to prioritize a CSS class?

Tags: css, css-specificity

I'm referencing to some bootstrap style sheet and there's a definition for

```
.badge {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 10px;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background-color: #777;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.alert-success {
    color: #3c763d;
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    border-color: #d6e9c6;
}
```

I want to use this style but due to my HTML `class="alert-success badge"`, it's overridden by the other definition

```
.panel-default>.panel-heading .badge {
    color: #f5f5f5;
    background-color: #333;
}
```

Now that the latter definition is more specific, it prioritize over my desired CSS. How can I resolve this?

**EDIT:**
There are a lot more other classes that have this issue. Is there a solution I don't need to specify them one by one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), you should just override the more specific selector with your own.

```
.panel-default > .panel-heading .badge.alert-success {
    color: #3c763d;
    background-color: #dff0d8;
    border-color: #d6e9c6;
}
```

**Edit:** Other options can include:

1. Removing/Altering the offending CSS file (difficult with bootstrap, but doable, and maintenance headache if you decide to update bootstrap.css)

   - Update/remove offending selectors
   - Adding `:not()` selector to avoid certain scenarios
2. Altering your HTML Structure so that it does **NOT** follow the offending CSS selectors.

   - Changing class names and/or using new ones
   - Inserting/Deleting additional nested divs/elements (to avoid `>` direct-child selector)

Thankfully, if you have lots of classes to update, a [smart regex replace](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions) is your best friend, but that's another topic.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear, this is not what I want to do because there are a lot more other classes that have this issue. I don't want to do it one by one.

Comment: Is there anything in common you can extract from those other classes?

Comment: They all have different values for ``color`` and ``background-color``. I guess maybe it's more like can I somehow ignore that specific badge css?

Comment: Sadly there isn't another way unless you modify your HTML structure (you may lose other CSS declarations that bootstrap grants). I personally have had multiple projects where this happens, and in order to preserve other beneficial CSS, I would *duplicate* their selectors and set my own values. Since my CSS would be loaded after *bootstrap*, my CSS would take priority.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like there's no easy and elegant solution, so I just did my simple workaround. I copied out the badge css and gave it a new name to use instead of using the bootstrap badge class. Sad.

```
.panel-default > .panel-heading .alert-badge {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 10px;
    padding: 3px 7px;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 700;
    line-height: 1;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ID` selector has higher specificity priority than `CLASS`. If you can able to add **id**, it will over-ride `.panel-default>.panel-heading .badge`

```
.panel-default>.panel-heading .badge {
    color: #f5f5f5;
    background-color: #333;
}

#custom.badge{
  background-color: #f00;
}


<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
    <div class="badge">class target</div>
    <div id="custom" class="anything badge">id target</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's the mozilla documentaion for specificity,
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You know what I'm not sure if your solution is even registering as css. I had to do this to even get a result to show. I think the CSS was just off syntax wise.

```
.panel-default > .panel-heading, .panel-default > .badge{
    color: #f5f5f5;
    background-color: #333;
}
```

I only noticed this because I actually tested out my code this time.